# xfs_quota apply for all users under /home

Tags: rhel, xfs, quota

in RHEL 8.9, I have a 100gb XFS formatted `/home` partition; all local user accounts in `/etc/passwd` have their home directories under `/home`. And all user accounts primary gid is and will always be 100 {users}.

I would like to apply a quota of 1GB per user on their `/home` account as an administration effort to manage data.  I have 80 users currently in `/etc/passwd` can expect it to grow back up over 150.

I currently have in `/etc/fstab`

```
UUID=12345   /home   xfs    defaults,nodev,nosuid,uquota,gquota    0 0
```

- What are the correct arguments to pass to the `xfs_quota` command?
- If I have 80 users, do I have to do 80 `xfs_quota` commands one for each account under `/home`?  Or can it be done with one command instance?
- should a `mount -o remount /home` work?  I'm finding it doesn't and either a successful `umount` or `reboot` is needed.  Will a `umount -l` work?  How dangerous is this on an active system with users logged in?
- For all new users in the future, will a new `xfs_quota` need to be performed on their home folder or is there a way to have it automatically applied?

Answer (score 0):

- `xfs_quota` needs the `-x` option (supposedly "expert mode") to do anything useful. This is very easy to overlook.
- If you want to give all 80 users the same quota, you could do something like:

  ```shell
  for user in $(awk -F: '($3 > 1000 && $3 < 60000){print $1}' /etc/passwd); do \
  xfs_quota -x -c "limit -u bhard=1024m $user" /home; done
  ```
- I think you need to set `uquota` (or `gquota`) at mount time. I don't think you can switch it on (or off) with a remount.
- For a default quota, you can set a quota for UID 0 - that will be used as the default quota for any user that does not have a specific quota set.
  For example, you could create a test FS:

  ```shellsession
  # mkdir /mnt/test
  # lvcreate -L 1G -n test datavg
  # mkfs.xfs /dev/mapper/datavg-test
  # mount /dev/mapper/datavg-test /mnt/test -o uquota
  # xfs_quota -x -c "report" /mnt/test
  User quota on /mnt/test (/dev/mapper/datavg-test)
                                 Blocks
  User ID          Used       Soft       Hard    Warn/Grace
  ---------- --------------------------------------------------
  root                0          0          0     00 [--------]
  ```
- Then you could set a specific quota (100k for UID 101), and a default quota (200k for UID 0):

  ```shellsession
  # xfs_quota -x -c "limit -u bhard=100k 101" /mnt/test
  # xfs_quota -x -c "limit -u bhard=200k 0" /mnt/test
  ```
- Then if you create some data owned by UID 101 (with a specific quota) and UID 102 (with no specific quota), and look at a quota report:

  ```shellsession
  # dd if=/dev/zero of=/mnt/test/f1 bs=1k count=10; chown 101 /mnt/test/f1
  # dd if=/dev/zero of=/mnt/test/f2 bs=1k count=10; chown 102 /mnt/test/f2
  # xfs_quota -x -c "report" /mnt/test
  User quota on /mnt/test (/dev/mapper/datavg-test)
                                 Blocks
  User ID          Used       Soft       Hard    Warn/Grace
  ---------- --------------------------------------------------
  root                0          0        200     00 [--------]
  #101               12          0        100     00 [--------]
  #102               12          0        200     00 [--------]
  ```

You can see that UID 101 has the specific quota that was set, but UID 102 inherited the default quota.